# meteor app failing when i run "meteor run android"

Tags: meteor

My app is failing when i run "meteor run android". I running meteor on fedora 23. I think its an issue with the emulator because when it reaches the point of calling the emulator, thats when it fails. 
Below is what the terminal gives:

```
[root@localhost first-app]# meteor run android
[[[[[ /home/karakireronald/Meteor-Projects/first-app ]]]]]

=> Started proxy.                             
=> Started MongoDB.                           
=> Errors executing Cordova commands:                                                

While running Cordova app for platform Android with options --emulator:
   Error: Command failed:                     
   /home/karakireronald/Meteor-Projects/first-app/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/android/cordova/run
   --emulator
   { [Error: adb: Command failed with exit code 126 Error output:
   /root/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb: /root/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb:
   cannot execute binary file] code: 126 } 'Error: adb: Command failed with
   exit code 126 Error output:\n/root/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb:
   /root/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb: cannot execute binary file\n    at
   ChildProcess.whenDone
   (/home/karakireronald/Meteor-Projects/first-app/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/cordova-common/src/superspawn.js:169:23)\n
   at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)\n    at ChildProcess.emit
   (events.js:172:7)\n    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:829:16)\n
   at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit
   (internal/child_process.js:211:5)'
   at ChildProcess.exitCallback (/tools/utils/processes.js:151:23)
   at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
   at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
   at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:200:12)

/root/.meteor/packages/less/.2.6.5.1m3fc8s++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.compileLessBatch.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/promise/node_modules/meteor-promise/promise_server.js:165
      throw error;
      ^
ExitWithCode:1
```

Comment: Have you set up your Android Virtual Device correctly? Sometimes having the AVD emulator running before executing your Meteor app helps.

Comment: well i have the same issue but it also happened with iOS emulator as well .

Comment: I am also getting error : ubuntu@ip-172-31-22-20:~/meteor/myapp$  meteor run android
[[[[[ ~/meteor/myapp ]]]]]

=> Started proxy.
/home/ubuntu/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.6.1_1.c76v6p.io9tw++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/meteor-promise/promise_server.js:218
      throw error;
      ^

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/home/ubuntu/meteor/myapp/icons/icon-60@2x.png'